# creating and deleting shapes in vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

When creating a shape in excel an automatic name is generated eg "Click Box 213". This would be the 213th shape created. My shapes are created by a macro copying lines in an excel sheet. How to identify the last shape created so I can perform operating on it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.Count` property on the `Shapes` collection

```
Set lastShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes(ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count))
```